# How to find which stored procedure is called by a job

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server database user with low access. I can see the jobs but I don't have access to maintenance plans to see which stored procedure is called by those jobs.

I want to find out the name of the stored procedure that is called by a given job. How can I do this with my account access?

Comment: Saying "low access" is no good. What is the SQL Server? MS, Oracle, other? What is your SQL Server access role? Can you see the job details?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just ask the Database Administrator who looks after the database?

Comment: the database is on microsoft SQl Server 2008R2
I don't know what is my account role
i just can see the jobs and its details but in details there isn't any name of stored procedure
i just want to find Sp name that called by jobs

Comment: You aren't double clicking enough....what exactly do you see when you double click the individual steps? what step type is indicated?

Comment: I can just see the job properties
.... I want to see the Store procedure name that called by that job like as maintenance plans but i don't have permission to see maintenance plans....... is there any other place except maintenance plans or T-SQL command to see the SP name ????????

Comment: What happens when you double click the job - do you get an error message or does your monitor turn off?

Comment: When i click the job just see the jobs properties....... I just want to know what SP is calling when i execute the job

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the job in SQL Server Agents, then you can script it by going to,

*SQL Server Agent --> Jobs -->  --> Right Click --> Script Job As --> CREATE TO --> New Query Editor Window.*

You will get the script behind job. There you can see stored procedures being called.

If your account doesn't allow to do even this, run your job and at the same time run *SQL Server Profiler* on your server, good possibility that you can see the stored procedures getting executed against your job name.

Comment: Thank you for your solution but that's not work....... In jobs Script there isn't any name of Sp that called............ And for the an other solution i don't have permission to run SQL Server Profiler ........... Is there any way ???????????

Comment: Whatever the job is supposed to do, that is there in the script. You have the script, you have everything you need. Job is nothing but that code written getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

This is my jobs script.......

```
USE [msdb]
GO

/****** Object:  Job [IstgSms48.SendSms]    Script Date: 05/16/2016 12:25:12 ب.ظ ******/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0
/****** Object:  JobCategory [Database Maintenance]    Script Date: 05/16/2016 12:25:12 ب.ظ ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'Database Maintenance' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'Database Maintenance'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'IstgSms48.SendSms', 
        @enabled=0, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=2, 
        @notify_level_email=0, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'No description available.', 
        @category_name=N'Database Maintenance', 
        @owner_login_name=N'IstgBazian', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
/****** Object:  Step [SendSms]    Script Date: 05/16/2016 12:25:14 ب.ظ ******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'SendSms', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'SSIS', 
        @command=N'/Server "$(ESCAPE_NONE(SRVR))" /SQL "Maintenance Plans\IstgSms48" /set "\Package\SendSms.Disable;false"', 
        @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, @name=N'IstgSms48.SendSms', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @freq_type=4, 
        @freq_interval=1, 
        @freq_subday_type=4, 
        @freq_subday_interval=1, 
        @freq_relative_interval=0, 
        @freq_recurrence_factor=0, 
        @active_start_date=20150312, 
        @active_end_date=99991231, 
        @active_start_time=0, 
        @active_end_time=235959, 
        @schedule_uid=N'3e6d4d84-da6c-4e08-a36e-34b105b7ffaf'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:

GO
```